# Empty input field gets filled

Tags: php

I've made a password reset option. Users can fill in their emailaddress and an email will be sent to the addres. The email contains an URL where the user can fill in a new password. Some validation and sanitazion is done and submitted to the database.

In both my forms I have an input field with `display:none`. If this field has a value, an error will be returned on submitting the form. I've made this to prevent robots from filling in the form.

The first form where the user fills in their emailaddress submits without any errors. However when I fill in a new password and submit, I get the error message linked with the input field with `display:none`.

The weird thing is that this only happens on one computer. I've tested this on one computer with Firefox and Safari, worked perfectly. On the other computer Safari works fine, Firefox returns the error. I've checked for automatically information that could be filled in, but found nothing.

My code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
   echo "Failure. 
   Click <a href=\"registration.php\">here</a> to return."; 
}

<form action="password_lost.php?t=<?php echo $_GET['t'] . "&e=" . $_GET['e']; ?>" method="POST">  
        <input type="text" class="email" style="display:none;" name="email" value="" />
        <input type="password" name="password" size="30"> 
        <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Submit" />
</form> 

$_GET['t'] = a token
$_GET['e'] = the emailaddress
```

How is it possible that this only happens with one browser, with only one form.

Comment: The browser is probably set to auto-fill passwords. Remove the saved password from that machine.

Comment: The browser auto-complete functionality ?

Comment: You are going to have to have to show us the server side code...

Comment: I've removed the entire auto-fill entry of my webpage, but still it returns the error. @superphonic, what more server side code do you need? The error is within these lines as the rest of the script doesn't get executed.

Comment: How is the error within this code? The `!empty($_POST['date']` is looking for a `date` field, yet there is no input with that name in your form?!?

Comment: Should've been 'email', my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing your browsers cache and setting autocomplete to off.

Firefox:
For passwords, go to Edit > Preferences > Privacy & Security > Passwords and uncheck the option to remember passwords. Note that passwords can be stored in an encrypted format.

Comment: The problem was indeed the cache and the password entry in Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, how to do a cache refresh use `CTRL + F5` @Nijn more on cache refreshes and browsers take a look at this post's answer : http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why browsers behave differently here, but why don't you add `autocomplete="off"` ? Like so:

```
<input type="text" class="email" style="display:none;" name="email" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: This did fix my problem, but autocomplete is an attribute of HTML 5 and I don't want to rely on that. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
```

To this:

```
if($_POST['email']) {
```

Also I would do `print_r($_POST)` so you can see what is being submitted by the form. See if what is being submitted changes based on browser and PC.

Comment: Would indeed be a good way to debug the hidden field. It was a cache problem and I will change the line like you said, much more efficient.